# I am trying to take 1020 to the 275th power, and modding that by 1073, but java wont output the right answer

Tags: java, math, exponent

i am working on a decoder, and i need to take 1020 to the 275th power, and mod that by 1073, but when i do try that, it wont print out the correct answer

```
    double decoded = (1020^275)%1073;
```

That is the code i am trying, but it will print out 751, and its supposed to print 4, anyone have any tips?

Comment: `^` is not an exponentiation operator.

Comment: "*`1020^275`*" - this is not the power function, but the bitwise xor. Even if it were the power function, the `275`th power of `1020` would be a number with `825` digits (at least). No way to fit this in a `double`.

Comment: Search for *modular exponentiation*.

Answer (score 3):

`^` is the `xor` operator; however, 1020 to the 275th power is a **HUGE** number and **will** overflow even if using `double` or `long`, so it should be represented by `BigInteger`:

```
System.out.println(BigInteger.valueOf(1020).pow(275).mod(BigInteger.valueOf(1073)));
```

Output:

```
4
```

**Note**: I used `BigInteger#mod`, but `BigInteger#remainder` will return the same value in your case (as you're only dealing with non-negative values).

Comment: Definitely recommend `BigInteger` over `BigDecimal` if you know integers are all that is required.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
BigDecimal remainder = new BigDecimal(1020).pow(275).remainder(new BigDecimal(1073));
System.out.println(remainder);
```

After applying remainder, it can be converted to long as its max value will be 1072(in this case):

```
remainder.longValueExact();
```

Comment: what data type do i save it as

Comment: BigDecimal. Double/Long cannot be used as ti will overflow with this huge number.

It can be converted to long value with remainder.longValueExact()

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BigInteger.pow()` followed by `BigInteger.mod()`.

However the BigInteger class specifically includes in operation for your task: [`BigInteger.modPow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow-java.math.BigInteger-java.math.BigInteger-):

```
System.out.println(BigInteger.valueOf(1020).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(275), BigInteger.valueOf(1073)));
```

gives 4.

Answer (score 1):

`double` is bounded and has precision limitations, try:

```
System.out.println(Math.pow(1020, 275));  // Infinity
```

Usually, you should use `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger` to manipulate big numbers,

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(1020);
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.pow(275);
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.remainder(new BigDecimal(1073));
System.out.println(bigDecimal); //4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Xor is differ from power function. 2 ^ 3, The output of an XOR gate is true only when exactly one of its inputs is true. If both of an XOR gate's inputs are false, or if both of its inputs are true, then the output of the XOR gate is false.
double maximum value = 1.7976931348623157E308
Actually (1020^275) = 2.3176467070363862212063591722218e+827 which greater than double maximum value.

Go with BigDecimal.

System.out.println(new BigDecimal(1020.0).pow(275).remainder(new BigDecimal(1073)));
```